# Android - reuse classes in different projects with different R imports?

Tags: java, android, import, code-reuse

I was wondering if there is a way to reuse my classes in Android projects where the only thing that changes is the R import?

So for example I have one file saved where the import is :

```
import com.myname.project.R
```

And in my second project the class is exactly the same as the one in the first project except it's import for the R file is different:

```
import com.myname.projecttwo.R
```

This means I have to maintain two files with just the import being different, son when I change something in one I have to remember to change it in the other.

Is there a standard way to avoid this and have only one file where I can change whatever I want and I will be able to use it in both projects?

Comment: did you know about Android Library project in eclipse ... http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a lot of shared code, you probably should be using a library project to keep your codebase and then two different projects with your resources.

Android Developer explains it nicely, see: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects.

Comment: Can I use a Library project with applications built for API level 7 though?

Comment: I build for level 7, and I used to use a source library myself, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you need that line at all. I do not have it in any of my modules, and if one ever does it is usually an error. As far as I know, that include should be generated automatically. I am no expert on this and I can feel a downvote coming here, but that is my experience as a jobbing programmer. I do have a package statement though, and I would need to change that if I wanted to reuse the code.

Comment: Without the R import I have no reference to my UI components and my code will fail to compile.

Comment: As I said in my answer, I think that reference is generated automatically, or at least it should be. But I do not know what settings in Eclipse trigger that, or if it is done some other way.

Comment: Ah OK, that won't work for me, I need to be able to keep a single file in a source database and pull that down to each project when required.

Comment: In that case a source library sounds like the way to go.